# Add active admin comments during edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm trying to add `ActiveAdmin::Comment` to my `Member` edit. I have been able to do this by adding an ARB and a partial

```
#_comments.html.arb
active_admin_comments_for(resource)
```

This displays properly but when I type in text then press the add comment button, the comment isn't actually added, it just goes back to the show screen.

What I am trying to do is get the comments in there, but not have the Add Comment button. I would like to add a comment by pressing the `Update Member` button. This way any changes done to the member will be saved with the comment at the same time.

Is there a way to have it so comments are added with the `Update Member` button?

**EDIT:**

I have also tried adding a relation in my model

```
#model
has_many :comments, as: :resource, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'ActiveAdmin::Comment'
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, reject_if: :reject_comment


# members.rb - form
f.inputs "Add A Comment" do
  f.semantic_fields_for :comments, ActiveAdmin::Comment.new do |c|
    c.inputs :class => "" do
      c.input :resource_id, :input_html => { :value => "1" }, as: :hidden
      c.input :resource_type, :input_html => { :value => "Member" }, as: :hidden
      c.input :namespace, :input_html => { :value => :admin }, as: :hidden
      c.input :body, :label => "Comment"
    end
  end
end
```

However, even with the permitted params it still doesn't save as a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up finally getting this working.

**models/Members.rb**

```
has_many :comments, as: :resource, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'ActiveAdmin::Comment'
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, reject_if: :reject_comment

def reject_comment(comment)
    return comment['body'].blank?
end
```

**app/Members.rb**

```
# in the controller section of controller do
def update(options={}, &block)
  params[:member][:comments_attributes]['0']['namespace'] = 'admin'
  params[:member][:comments_attributes]['0']['author_id'] = current_admin_user.id
  params[:member][:comments_attributes]['0']['author_type'] = 'AdminUser'
  # This is taken from the active_admin code
  super do |success, failure|
    block.call(success, failure) if block
    failure.html { render :edit }
  end
end

# in the form portion
f.inputs "Add A Comment" do
  f.semantic_fields_for :comments, ActiveAdmin::Comment.new do |c|
    c.inputs :class => "" do
      c.input :body, :label => "Comment", :input_html => { :rows => 4 }
    end
  end
end
```

This allows me to have a field called `Comment` and if I want to add the comment while I edit the `Member` I can do this and save the comment when I press the `f.actions` button `Update Member`

Comment: Hey there - I'm actually trying to do something similar -- use the comments as an almost git commit.   Thanks for this - it's going to be part of what I utilize, but I'm also looking to overload the delete / destroy so that the 'are you sure you want to' popup is a text input that forces one to add a comment or not delete; did you try anything similar?

Comment: how to permit the comments params? I am getting error as unpermitted_parameters :comments_attributes.... Rails verison is 4.2.6

Answer (score 1):

So recentrly I stumbled upon the same problem and here is my version which is fully based on Bot’s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40252337/3934708) above, but a bit more universal:

#### Model

```rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :resource, dependent: :destroy,
           class_name: 'ActiveAdmin::Comment'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, allow_destroy: true,
                                reject_if: -> (comment) { comment['body'].blank? }
end
```

#### ActiveAdmin resource

Explicitly listing all `comments_attributes`’ attributes is necessary.

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  permit_params comments_attributes: [:author_id, :author_type, :body, :namespace, :_destroy]
end
```

#### Patch `update` in ActiveAdmin controller

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  controller do
    def update(options={}, &block)

      # Adds known data of ActiveAdmin comment
      params[resource.class.name.downcase][:comments_attributes]['0'].merge!({
        author_id:   current_admin_user.id,
        author_type: current_admin_user.class.name,
        namespace:   ActiveAdmin::Devise.config[:path]
      })

      super do |success, failure|
        block.call(success, failure) if block
        failure.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note that here we dynamically get tye class of base resource `resource.class.name.downcase`, class & id of the admin user, as well as Devise scope for admin (some people customize their `/admin` namespace): `ActiveAdmin::Devise.config[:path]`

#### Form fields

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs ActiveAdmin::Comment.model_name.human(count: "other") do
      # Remove `, ActiveAdmin::Comment.new`, and all the previous comments will be rendered as <textareax>
      f.semantic_fields_for :comments, ActiveAdmin::Comment.new do |c|
        c.input :body, input_html: { rows: 4, required: false }
      end
    end

    f.actions
  end
end
```

Alternative. This way all existing comments will appear as `<textarea>`s:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  form do |f|
    f.has_many :comments, allow_destroy: true do |c|
      c.input :body, input_html: { rows: 4, required: false }
    end

    f.actions
  end
end
```

#### Add translation if you need

`active_admin_comment.yml`

```yaml
---
ru:
  activerecord:
    models:
      active_admin/comment:
        zero:  Служебных комментариев
        one:   Служебный комментарий
        few:   Служебных комментария
        many:  Служебных комментариев
        other: Служебные комментарии

    attributes:
      active_admin/comment:
        body: Комментарий
```